# Connecting Chrome Extension to StackExchange oAuth API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, oauth

**TL;DR** -- I am trying to build a Chrome extension that displays the number of current notifications for a user from StackOverflow.

I am following the [Chrome Extension tutorial](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_oauth) on creating an extension that utilizes oAuth. Swapping out the Google oAuth bits for (what I think are) the StackExchange API bits, I end up with the following in my `background.js` file:

```
var oauth = ChromeExOAuth.initBackgroundPage({
    //ES6 template strings!
    'request_url'   : `https://stackexchange.com/oauth?client_id=${STACK_APP.id}&scope=read_inbox,no_expiry`, 

    'authorize_url' : 'https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success',
    'access_url'    : 'https://stackexchange.com/oauth/access_token',

    'consumer_key'    : STACK_APP.key,
    'consumer_secret' : STACK_APP.secret,

    //'scope'    : '', //not sure I need this...

    'app_name' : 'StackOverflow Notifications (Chrome Extension)'
});

oauth.authorize(function () {
    console.log('authorize...');
});
```

When I run the extension locally, it attempts to open a new browser tab to complete the oAuth handshake -- which is great, except that I end up at the following URL:
    https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success?oauth_token=undefined

The browser tab gets stuck here.[image]

I'm not really sure what the problem is - I don't know if I have the wrong URLs listed in my `initBackgroundPage()` call, or if my StackApp has the wrong oAuth domain (since it's a Chrome extension... [this question](https://stackapps.com/questions/3294/registering-app-for-api-2-0-key-without-oauth-domain) didn't really answer things for me).

Any ideas would be most appreciated!

Comment: Would it be unsporting to point to an existing open-source one?

Comment: I will probably end up putting my code on GitHub... when I do, I'll post the link for reference.

Comment: No-no, would it be unsporting to give _you_ a link to another extension that already exists? Do you want to make yours without being tainted by others' ideas? Granted, now that I re-read your question, the one I have in mind is a notifier that does not display the counter.

Comment: Ha, thanks for the offer. I prefer to struggle through this, it's going pretty well at this point :-)

Comment: FYI: https://github.com/arthurakay/StackOverflow-Notifications

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I can tell, the oAuth tutorial I mentioned in my OP is outdated -- you no longer need any of that, you can use `chrome.identity` instead.

To be clear, there are a few things I had to do:

```
STACK_APP = {
    id           : 1234,
    scope        : 'read_inbox,no_expiry',

    request_uri  : 'https://stackexchange.com/oauth/dialog',
    redirect_uri : chrome.identity.getRedirectURL("oauth2")
};

//ES6 template string!
var requestUrl = `${STACK_APP.request_uri}?client_id=${STACK_APP.id}&scope=${STACK_APP.scope}&redirect_uri=${STACK_APP.redirect_uri}`;


//https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/identity
//https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/app_identity#update_manifest
chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow({
    url         : requestUrl,
    interactive : true
}, function (url) {
    console.log('redirected to: ' + url);
});
```

Note the `redirect_uri` -- this ends up being a subdomain of chromiumapp.org, so you need to list that in StackApps as the domain for your app (allowing oAuth to continue).

Comment: you saved the day my man. I have been struggling to get my chrome extension to work. All I had to do was add `chromiumapp.org` in my apps `OAuth Domain`

Comment: Related question: https://stackapps.com/a/9454/96492